# visual studio 2019 version c# probleme

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I can not change the version of C # on visual studio 2019

I tried to go to the property to access a window that normally allowed to change the version of C #

Error CS8025 The 'local functions' feature is not available in C # 4. Use version 7.0 or later.

Comment: Could you please provide your code.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of that VS window?

Comment: It seems to be that you are able to change C# version, but after changing the version to C# 4.0 you get some compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using .Net Core. Within the .csproj file for your start-up project (executable, web, web API, whichever it is in your case), add the following:

`<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>`

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) for more details.

Comment: excuse me I started but I did not understand, where should I put the changes precisely

Comment: Your solution should contain one or more project files that have the extension .csproj. In Visual Studio, they look more like folders than files, it doesn't show the extension, and it won't let you edit them for projects that are loaded. Find the one that you've set as the start-up project in the solution explorer, right-click and select "Unload project", right-click the project again an there should be an option to edit the .csproj file. It should be an XML file where the root element is a `Project` tag. Add the lines in the answer anywhere inside the `Project` tag.

Comment: Alternatively, if you hit ctrl+q, and search for "language" there should be an option to enable the latest language features.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on your csproj in the solution explorer.
- Select properties.
- Select 'Build' near the top left of the screen.
- Click 'Advanced' in the main window (scroll down if you can't see it).
- Change language version to latest minor version.

Comment: The problem is that this window has been broken and the combobox has been disabled. This is the bug the question refeers to.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to edit the language in the property page.
I had to add this to the csproj which was not able to build.
in the propertyGroup, right where AsseblyName is for my .netcore 3 project.

```
<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
```

you should probably use the version according to your .net framework version, the table is here:

The compiler determines a default based on these rules:

```
DEFAULTS
Target          framework   C# language version default
.NET            6.x         C# 10
.NET            5.x         C# 9.0
.NET Core       3.x         C# 8.0
.NET Core       2.x         C# 7.3
.NET Standard   2.1         C# 8.0
.NET Standard   2.0         C# 7.3
.NET Standard   1.x         C# 7.3
.NET Framework  all         C# 7.3
```

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version