# Changing the C# version in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm using visual studio 2019 and I'm trying to change my C# version. The reason I am doing this is that the build servers I use use an older version of VS / MSBuild to build and deploy code (this is outside my control). Therefore I need to use C# 5.

On previous versions of visual studio, you could do this from the menu in [Project] -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced.
For VS2019 Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, has decided to make this harder. Apparently you need to edit the project file manually and add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>[some version here]</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To your project file manually. That's all well and good, but I can't seem to get that working. It just ignores it, even after I unload and reload it. Here is a snapshot of my project file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>5</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{58FE5465-851B-471F-B6A9-9C861FA5C022}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
...
```

Any idea how I can make this work? It's probably something really silly I'm missing.
Note: I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149841/visual-studio-2019-version-c-sharp-probleme) previous question but it was lacking detail.

Comment: Have you tried the Directory.Build.props route described [here](https://www.meziantou.net/4-ways-to-enable-the-latest-csharp-features.htm) ?

Comment: (examines project **Properties.Build.Advanced** and notices it is now `grayed out`!  [Tell me more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version))  Thanks, I learnt something new today.  The sooner .NET 5 gets here the better.  Though for all we know we'll all be forced to use YAML :(

Comment: What framework version are you on? Have you checked that there isn't another `LangVersion` element further down the file? What arguments are you passing to MSBuild on your build server? There might be something that overrides the settings in the csproj.

Comment: ps; is 5 a valid value for this element? Have you tried 5.0?

Comment: Did this declaration `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` help you?

Comment: How have you verified "it ignores it"? If you crank up the build verbosity, what's the command line used to build? If I do this with a fresh project file and add a `LangVersion` block, I get a `CoreCompile:` step that includes a `csc.exe` invocation that uses `/langversion:5`. In other words, this option gets passed down to the compiler, no problem. You may have incorrect expectations of what this option *does* -- it only restricts the constructs allowed in the source, it does not ensure the project or the build output is compatible with earlier versions of the .NET Framework or VS itself.

Comment: If the option is in effect and used by VS, code of the form `string s = null; int x = s?.Length;` will produce an error, as the null-conditional operator was introduced in C# 6.

Comment: @JeroenMostert changing the C# version ensures that incompatible code is marked as such, which means I know what changes to make for it to compile on older VS versions. This is not in relation to .NET version.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm not looking for the latest version, but an older one, so no.

Comment: @CaiusJard turns out both work now that I've fixed the underlying issue. I've added this to my solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out @lennart was right: There were some other `<LangVersion>`'s in the file. VS had snuck them into some of the build configurations.

```
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;PLATFORM_X86</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion> <-- HERE!!
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
```

**SOLUTION**:
I deleted all these configuration special cases and it defaulted back to the language I had listed at the top of the file.

I can tell it worked in my case because it now rejects interpolated strings (e.g. `$"{value}words"`) saying it's not available in C#5.

As for what language names work, both "5" and "5.0" worked for me. The rest of the options can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference)

I feel kind of dumb now, I hope this question will still be useful to some future people.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project, go to **Properties**, then click on **Build** in left pane, select C# version you want to keep or just select latest major version.
[image]

While saving, your {projectname}.csproj file's LangVersion property will be updated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change C# language version in Visual Studio 2019 is to:

1. Right-click on a project in Solution Explorer (files tree) in Visual Studio;
2. Then from the popup menu select "edit project item properties" -> "c# language level";
3. On the list you will see all possible c# versions.

That's it! It works like a charm. Please note, that you should not do any other changes to the project files - so if you did any, please revert them to the original state. Also you don't need any <LangVersion> tags.

Answer (score 1):

If Visual Studio does not allow you to change the language version, you need to proceed as follows, by editing the project file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

I had the same problem. I added the following line to  section:
7.3