# how to update IP rules in a Storage Account using the new Azure.ResourceManager package?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-storage-account

Can someone share sample code for how to update IP rules in a Storage Account using the new Azure.ResourceManager package?

I have to migrate code from the old Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent package to this new one and haven't been able to figure it out. Any leads would be appreciated!

This is what the current code using the old package looks like:

```
IAuthenticated azureActiveDirectroyClient = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(GetCredentials(<some_configuration>));
var subscriptionId = <subscription_id>;
var subscription = azureActiveDirectroyClient.WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
var storageAccount = await subscription.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroupAsync(<resource_grp_name>, <storage_account_name>).ConfigureAwait(false);

await storageAccount.Update().WithAccessFromAzureServices().WithAccessFromSelectedNetworks().WithAccessFromIpAddressRange(<some_ip_address_range>).ApplyAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await storageAccount.Update().WithAccessFromAzureServices().WithAccessFromSelectedNetworks().WithAccessFromIpAddress(<some_ip_address>).ApplyAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I need to replicate this functionality using the Azure.ResourceManager package (since the currently used package is deprecated)

Comment: Have you tried any code, if yes can you provide it in the question for reference?

Comment: Hi @DasariKamali, I have added the code snippet in the question just now.

Comment: update IP rules in a Storage Account using Azure.ResourceManager [package](https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-account-network-rules/tree/master/)

Comment: Hi @Sampath, thanks for your answer. I referred to this sample (https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-account-network-rules/tree/master/) you have shared. Correct me if I am wrong but this is using the deprecated Microsoft.Azure.Management packages. I need the code to use the new Azure.ResourceManager package. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update IP rules in a Storage Account using Azure.ResourceManager package

- Using this reference to manage Network rules of a storage account using [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-account-network-rules/getting-started-on-managing-network-rules-of-a-storage-account-using-c/).
- Install  version 4.5 Or  Changing the C# version in Visual Studio 2019  from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247122/changing-the-c-sharp-version-in-visual-studio-2019#:%7E:text=Right%20click%20on%20the%20project%2C%20go%20to%20Properties%2C,your%20%7Bprojectname%7D.csproj%20file%27s%20LangVersion%20property%20will%20be%20updated.).

```
  Utilities.Log("Creating a Virtual network and subnet with storage service subnet access enabled:");

  INetwork network = azure.Networks.Define(networkName)
          .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
          .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
          .WithAddressSpace("10.0.0.0/28")
          .DefineSubnet(subnetName)
              .WithAddressPrefix("10.0.0.8/29")
              .WithAccessFromService(ServiceEndpointType.MicrosoftStorage)
              .Attach()
          .Create();

  Utilities.Log("Created a Virtual network with subnet:");
  Utilities.PrintVirtualNetwork(network);

  
  // Create a storage account with access to it allowed only from a specific subnet

  var subnetId = $"{network.Id}/subnets/{subnetName}";

  Utilities.Log($"Creating a storage account with access allowed only from the subnet{subnetId}");

  IStorageAccount storageAccount = azure.StorageAccounts.Define(storageAccountName)
          .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
          .WithExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
          .WithAccessFromSelectedNetworks()
          .WithAccessFromNetworkSubnet(subnetId)
          .Create();

  Utilities.Log("Created storage account:");
  Utilities.PrintStorageAccount(storageAccount);



  // Create a public IP address

  Utilities.Log("Creating a Public IP address");
```

- For other details Refer to Azure storage account  managing Network rules  [using C#](https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-account-network-rules/tree/master/) .

Comment: Hi @Sampath, thanks for your answer. I referred to this sample (https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-account-network-rules/tree/master/) you have shared. Correct me if I am wrong but this is using the deprecated Microsoft.Azure.Management packages. I need the code to use the new Azure.ResourceManager package. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: we can create network rules in the storage with Microsoft.Azure.Management for new refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-the-new-azure-sdk-resource-management-libraries-for-net/)